# editing fields, does not validate when inside a bootstrap accordion. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the xeditable library.

https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

When I try to edit a value in which I use this directive, I can do it since it is not inside the accordion, but if this is inside the accordion, the fields are not edited. Why does this happen?

https://plnkr.co/edit/s0y46xLFOhbGA3erGxJO?p=preview

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <a href="#" editable-text="user.name" onbeforesave="checkName($data)">
    {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
  </a> <!- wORKS HERE-->
    <uib-accordion>
      <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" is-open="status.open">
        <uib-accordion-heading>
            <a href="#" editable-text="user.name" onbeforesave="checkName($data)">
              {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
            </a> <!- NOT wORKS HERE-->
          <span ng-click="ignoreClick($event);">
            Text accordion
            <button ng-click="setMessage();">
              Click me
            </button>
          </span>
          <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
        </uib-accordion-heading>
        Some stuff
      </div>
    </uib-accordion>
    {{ message }}
  </div>
```

Comment: That PLNKR doesn't even have an editable-text in it. Not sure exactly what your issue is here. Please update your PLNKR to be relevant and that would help. Thanks.

Comment: @Scott man! thank you.. you has the reason... the link is updated.